# Flutter - Can we execute code Without opening the app by clicking on Notification Button?

Tags: android, swift, flutter, kotlin, dart

I'm getting Notification when the app is **open/closed**,

Step:- **killed** the app(*don't level on the background*), once you get a notification, click on any button of notification and perform a code(business logic) in it **without opening an app**?

Note:- I'm using an **awesome_notifications** PUB to get Action Button on Notifications.

to get notification in any case

````
```socketNotification(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      notificationSocketBackService.clearListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print("error :-=> $error");
    }
    String userid = "${await PreferenceHelper().getUserID()}";
    notificationSocketBackService = IO.io(
        socketURL,
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .setQuery({"user_id": "$userid"})
            .setExtraHeaders({'Upgrade': 'WebSocket', 'Connection': 'Upgrade'})
            .enableAutoConnect()
            .setReconnectionDelay(1)
            .enableReconnection()
            .build());

    notificationSocketBackService.on("checkConnection", (data) {
      isConnectedWithSocket = true;
    });

    notificationSocketBackService.on(
      "notificationToClient",
      (data) async {
        Map notificationData;
        try {
          notificationData =
              jsonDecode(data.toString().replaceAll("node", '"node"'));
        } catch (e) {
          print("CounterService object e :-=> $e");
          notificationData = {"error": "No notifications found"};
        }
        if (jsonEncode(notificationData).contains("error")) {
          return;
        } else {
          List<NotificationActionButton> actionButtons = [];
          Map notificationPayload = notificationData["node"];
          if (notificationPayload["type"] == "FlyingLike" &&
              notificationPayload["flyingLikeStatus"] == "Requested" &&
              notificationPayload.containsKey("flyingLikeID") &&
              notificationPayload["flyingLikeID"] != null &&
              notificationPayload["flyingLikeID"] != "") {
            //
            actionButtons.add(
              NotificationActionButton(
                key: Constants.accept,
                label: Constants.accept,
              ),
            );
            actionButtons.add(
              NotificationActionButton(
                key: Constants.reject,
                label: Constants.reject,
              ),
            );
          } else if (notificationPayload["type"] == "Like") {
            //
            actionButtons.add(
              NotificationActionButton(
                key: Constants.like,
                label: Constants.like,
              ),
            );
          } else if (notificationPayload["type"] == "Match") {
            if (appLifecycleState != AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
              return;
              //
              actionButtons.add(
                NotificationActionButton(
                  key: Constants.viewMatch,
                  label: Constants.viewMatch,
                ),
              );
              return;
            }
            return;
          } else {
          }
          String description = "";
          if (notificationPayload["type"] == "Match") {
            description = notificationPayload["description"] +
                " to " +
                notificationPayload["sender"]["firstName"];
          } else {
            description = notificationPayload["description"];
          }
          await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
            content: NotificationContent(
              id: notificationPayload["id"].hashCode,
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              title: '${notificationPayload["title"]}',
              body: '${description}',
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
              payload: {"node": "${data["node"]}"},
              createdSource: NotificationSource.Firebase,
            ),
            actionButtons: actionButtons,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```
````

to perform a execute on click oF any button of notification
below code run at home screen were we get loaded all data of user which need

```
AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((notification) {
          if (notification.channelKey == 'basic_channel' && Platform.isIOS) {
            AwesomeNotifications().getGlobalBadgeCounter().then(
                  (value) =>
                      AwesomeNotifications().setGlobalBadgeCounter(value - 1),
                );
          }

          getButtonKeyPressedAction(notification);
        });
```

Comment: you can use work manager for this.

Comment: @NadimAnsari it provides only notification but when I click on the button of notification button it's open the app and executes a business logic

Comment: add Code of Notification in your question